# I have downloaded code from bit bucket and tried to run the project, google maps showing a blank screen.

Tags: android, google-maps

I have downloaded code from bit bucket  and tried to run the project, why my google maps showing a blank screen. But it works perfectly when i will run the code by apk. please help.

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow** Have a look **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and Please read how to create [mcve]

Comment: Have you change the google api key?

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that your **GOOGLE_API_KEY** generated for debug or release mode. Try to change API Key

```
<string name="google_api_debug_key" translatable="false">GOOGLE_API_KEY</string>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks buddy i have added the package name and finger print now it's working.